# ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list). When I train my model

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

Hello I have some issue with the convert of Numpy array to a Tensor

`generator_model.fit([np.random.randn(len(image_train), LATENT_DIM), text_train], image_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=EPOCHS, validation_data=([np.random.randn(len(image_val), LATENT_DIM), text_val], image_val))`

The code make this error : `ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).`

here are the variables image_train, image_val, text_train, text_val : `image_train, image_val, text_train, text_val = train_test_split(images, texts, test_size=0.2)`

here are the variables images and texts :

```
data = pd.read_csv('data/captions.csv', delimiter=',')
captions = data['caption'].values
image_paths = "data/images/" + data['filename'].values

def load_image(image_path):
    return np.array(Image.open(image_path).resize((IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE)))

images = np.array([load_image(path) for path in image_paths])
texts = np.array([tf.keras.preprocessing.text.one_hot(caption, TEXT_EMBEDDING_DIM) for caption in captions])
```

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks !

I try to make a AI model for text to image generation

Comment: The error in which line?

Comment: The error is on this line : generator_model.fit([np.random.randn(len(image_train), LATENT_DIM), text_train], image_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=EPOCHS, validation_data=([np.random.randn(len(image_val), LATENT_DIM), text_val], image_val)

Comment: The code is very annoying, could you please use variables to store formulas: for example `laten_train = np.random.randn(len(image_train), LATENT_DIM)`

Comment: Like this ? : generator_model.fit([laten_train], image_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=EPOCHS, validation_data=([laten_val, text_val], image_val))

Comment: Yes, it improves the readability of your code, otherwise, it is very difficult for others to read it and debug it.

Comment: Ok, I think thé problem is the variable texts. This var doesn't want to be convert in a Tensor

Comment: Did you fix the error?

Comment: No, I dont know how to convert the texts var in a Tensor

Comment: I do not find the texts var in the added code.

Comment: On the body Of this question, you have 3 lines Of code

Comment: texts = np.array([tf.keras.preprocessing.text.one_hot(caption, TEXT_EMBEDDING_DIM) for caption in captions])

Comment: What is the type of `caption`?

Comment: data = pd.read_csv('data/captions.csv', delimiter=',')
captions = data['caption'].values

Comment: What is the output of `print(type(captions))`?

Comment: return this : <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: Please declare new variables for every experssion and repost your question again, it is very difficult to be read. For example, `validation_data=([np.random.randn(len(image_val), LATENT_DIM), text_val], image_val))` what is it?